# JAX-WS - how to disable auto-response on @WebMethod?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

Is it possible to use only web request in method with annotation @WebMethod without response?
Or in ws we should always get response and I need somthing else?
It looks like

`@WebMethod
public void createUser(
    @WebParam(name="userInfo") 
    UserInfo userInfo)
        throws MyException`

in interface which was generated from wsdl. But when I sent a request to the server I got a response despite the void in the method.

And could you please advice books on this theme.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@Oneway` annotation

```
@WebMethod()
@Oneway()
public void insertUser(String username) {
 ...
}
```

***Documentation:***

> Indicates that the given @WebMethod has only an input message and no output. Typically, a oneway method returns the thread of control to the calling application prior to executing the actual business method. A 181 processor should report an error if an operation marked @Oneway has a return value or Holder parameters, or declares any checked exceptions.

The following [table summarizes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/e13750/annotations.htm#WSREF174) the standard JSR-181 annotations that you can use in your JWS file to specify the shape and behavior of your Web Service